# Is this a place where I can ask how I can improve my questions (for one category)?

Tags: discussion, questions

I think I've been around the community enough to know how to ask most questions properly.

However, I seem to get very quickly downvoted when I ask Git questions. Obviously, I am doing something wrong here.

Is this, Meta, an appropriate place to ask what I'm doing wrong in asking questions in this category?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes.  Yes, it is.  Did you have one specifically you needed to ask about? (You'd need a new Meta question for that now, but...)

Comment: @Makoto thanks. Yes, I'll write a new question. Want to put this as an answer?